# Splitting Exim mailboxes on two different disks

Tags: exim, maildir

I have inherited a rather small server and am forced to try splitting the e-mail accounts served by Exim on two (or more) disks (different mount points).

I was searching the internet for a solution but couldn't find one.

If at all possible, I want to be able to tell Exim on which mount point each e-mail address is and save accordingly.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What can be the reason to split the mailboxes?

Comment: Not enough disk space. The server is old, on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that Exim is configured as a traditional internet MTA.

I don't think you can configure Exim to store mail in a separate mount point per user, but you **can** change where Exim stores the mail for all accounts.

Open the default config and change the `file=` (for mbox delivery) or `directory=` (for maildir delivery) directive in the `local_delivery:` section. The massively large default Exim config is typically `/etc/mail/exim.conf`.

Change the `local_delivery` transport to a mountpoint with sufficient disk space and copy/move the existing mbox files or maildir folders there.